# How to use mktime() without changing the original tm struct?

Tags: c++, c

I've recently came up with a problem using the code:

```
time_t today_t;
time(&today_t);
tm *today = localtime(&today_t);

time_t tomorrow_t = mktime(today);
tomorrow_t += 86400;
tm *tomorrow = localtime(&tomorrow_t);
```

The problem is that my ***today*** object changes right after i use *localtime(&tomorrow_t)* to create ***tomorrow*** object, and values of both objects become equal. I don't really understand this behavior. Any help, please?

Comment: `time(&time_t)` should be `time(today_t)` ? Please copy paste your code, don't manually write a psuedo version

Comment: `today_t` is a poor name for a variable. The `_t` suffix is conventionally used for types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localtime` uses a single static variable for the `tm` struct and returns a pointer to it. Thus, `today` and `tomorrow` will have the same address.

There is a reentrant version `localtime_r` that takes a second argument where you can specify where the struct data is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the Linux man page for the `localtime` function:

> The return value points to a statically allocated struct which might
>   be overwritten by subsequent calls to  any of the date and time
>   functions.  The **`localtime_r()`** function does the same, but stores
>   the data in a user-supplied struct.

So if you call `localtime()` twice, it will return the same pointer value each time, overwriting it with the new value. `today` is a `struct tm*` pointer, which you own; `*today` is a `struct tm` object, which is owned by the C library.

Either copy the structure (not the pointer) to another `struct tm` object after the call or use `localtime_r` which writes to a structure that you supply. (`localtime_r` is not 100% portable; it's defined by POSIX, but not by the ISO C standard.)

Comment: Thanks very much for all the answers and especially for this one!